# Is Visual Basic Language supported in .NET6

Tags: vb.net, .net-core, asp.net-core-6.0

I want to upgrade my code from .NET4.8 to .net6 and I have code in visual basic and C# language so my question is that is visual basic supported on .net6 and if it is then what is the lowest version of visual basic that is supported in .net6 .

I have been finding resource online but i am not getting appropriate answer

Comment: Of course you can create a .Net 6+ Project (requires VS 2022) using VB.Net as language. Not sure what *the lowest version* means. You define the language version to use, adding the `<LangVersion>[Major].[Minor]</LangVersion>` tag to the Project's configuration file -- Why would you pick an older version of the language? To have *less options*?

Comment: There aren't many breaking changes https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/whats-new/breaking-changes so you likely can get by with the latest language version. You'll be spending more time dealing with the dependencies and framework changes.

Comment: there is a part in my project that is written in vb and rest is in C# so I want to keep vb part as it is while upgrading to .net6  because I do not have coding experience in vb language could that be possible

Comment: You should be concerned about the upgrade to the new .NET version rather than the language version. Don't confuse the language with the Framework

Answer (score 1):

Language support is backward compatible. You could ask what's the highest version the compiler would support. And yes, VB.NET is supported in net6 and further.

As per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/configure-language-version:

```
<PropertyGroup>
   <LangVersion>latest</LangVersion>
</PropertyGroup>
```

The value latest uses the latest minor version of the Visual Basic language. Valid values are:

| Value | Meaning |
| --- | --- |
| default | The compiler accepts all valid language syntax from the latest major version that it can support. |
| 9 | The compiler accepts only syntax that is included in Visual Basic 9.0 or lower. |
| 10 | The compiler accepts only syntax that is included in Visual Basic 10.0 or lower. |
| 11 | The compiler accepts only syntax that is included in Visual Basic 11.0 or lower. |
| 12 | The compiler accepts only syntax that is included in Visual Basic 12.0 or lower. |
| 14 | The compiler accepts only syntax that is included in Visual Basic 14.0 or lower. |
| 15 | The compiler accepts only syntax that is included in Visual Basic 15.0 or lower. |
| 15.3 | The compiler accepts only syntax that is included in Visual Basic 15.3 or lower. |
| 15.5 | The compiler accepts only syntax that is included in Visual Basic 15.5 or lower. |
| 16 | The compiler accepts only syntax that is included in Visual Basic 16 or lower. |
| 16.9 | The compiler accepts only syntax that is included in Visual Basic 16.9 or lower. |
| latest | The compiler accepts all valid language syntax that it can support. |